# All frequencies of my bar plot are the same height?

Tags: r

Trying to barplot a CSV file and the plot shows all categories as the same height despite the frequencies varying from 450-800

Below is the plot I receive

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbuyQ.jpg

I have tried implementing a height=x, width=x
This results in completely removing the labels and does not fix the initial problem.

```
setwd("~/Desktop")
causes<-read.csv('causes.csv')
head(causes)

table(causes$Intentional.self.harm..suicide)

barplot(table(causes$Intentional.self.harm..suicide))
barplot(table(causes$Intentional.self.harm..suicide), ylab='Frequency', 
        main='Barplot of Intentional self-harm (suicide)', col='lightblue'

dput(head(causes, 20))

Intentional.self.harm..suicide. = c(535L, 
579L, 480L, 541L, 499L, 537L, 466L, 453L, 459L, 494L, 520L, 553L, 
525L, 588L, 578L, 631L, 676L, 656L, 757L, 673L)
```

Comment: If the `table` output gives different frequencies, it is not clear how you are getting same height bars.  A reproducible example would be great.  `set.seed(24);barplot(table(sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)))`

Comment: please include your data

Comment: I'm very new to R so I'm not quite sure what you are asking, if you wanted me to import the code this is my result. !https://imgur.com/dsJ5wz3 also by including my data do you mean my CSV file?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(causes)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(causes, 20))`.

Comment: here is my dput(head(causes, 20)) ```Intentional.self.harm..suicide. = c(535L, 
579L, 480L, 541L, 499L, 537L, 466L, 453L, 459L, 494L, 520L, 553L, 
525L, 588L, 578L, 631L, 676L, 656L, 757L, 673L)```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using wrongly the `table` function since you already calculated the numbers of modalities. So it is not a graphical nor a functional problem. All you have to do is calculate the frequency as follow :

```r
Intentional.self.harm..suicide. = c(535L, 
                                    579L, 480L, 541L, 499L, 537L, 466L, 453L, 459L, 494L, 520L, 553L, 
                                    525L, 588L, 578L, 631L, 676L, 656L, 757L, 673L)

df <- Intentional.self.harm..suicide.
barplot(height = df) # correct barplot with counts

df_prop <- table(df) # gives a table that count modalities (all unique ie 1)
str(df_prop)

# With a data.frame if you want to include labels
df_prop <- data.frame(
        "type" = paste0("t", 1:20),
        "freq" = df/sum(df) # alternatively use prop.table(df)
)

# sum(df_prop$freq) # to check
barplot(height = df_prop$freq) # same 'profile' than first barplot

# --- EDIT / Follow up
# looking at documentation of barplot to set labels and ordinate limits
?barplot

barplot(height = df_prop$freq, names.arg = df_prop$type, ylim=c(0, max(df_prop$freq * 1.2)))
```

Comment: This works great thanks, but how would I label the bars with the data it shows?